# Partial reading of file in Java

Tags: java, file, api, io

I am creating a Java application in which I need to read the first few lines of a huge text file and do the processing.
Is it possible that instead of getting the entire file, I read the first few lines and fetch the data?  And this is being done using Java API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. When you use BufferedReader, for example, you read just (buffer_size) from the file. Then you can process it before reading the next fragment...

for example, see [this tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/BufferedReader.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Use [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

Answer (score 2):

There is also [LineNumberReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) if you need to keep track of the line numbers